# How to execute files added to .bashrc out of current directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, debian, sh

this is the content of my .bashrc file:

```
PATH=/kunden/xxx/rp-hosting/xxx/xxx/bin:$PATH
```

There is an executable version of composer in the `/kunden/xxx/rp-hosting/xxx/xxx/bin` directory.

I have placed a composer.json file in `/kunden/xxx/rp-hosting/xxx/xxx/dev.xxx.de/symfony`. But when cd to that directory and run `composer update` I get the following error:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /kunden/xxx/rp-hosting/xxx/xxx/bin
```

How can I make the executables in the bin dir make behave like they were executed in the current directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Composer showed an error that I was running the CGI version of php (stupid I know, I know). That was because I had an symlink in my bin dir to the cgi version. I changed the link it shows now to the CLI version of php. Now it works :)